# Do I need to cast inputs to int32 before computing powers of two with tensorflow on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to do a simple operation with tensorflow: *math_ops.pow(2, 13)*

When running on the CPU it works as expected and the result is 8192. However, if I run it on the GPU, there seems to be some numerical precision issue and the result is 8191.996.

I'm no expert on hardware so this might be something normal, however I found it interesting since this is quite a simple operation. My best guess is that it has something to do with how the GPU and the CPU work with *float32*.

Should I just take care of casting the inputs to *int* before computing the power of two?

If done with *ints*, it works perfectly fine:

```
math_ops.pow(2, 13)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=8192>
```

However, if you try to run the same with *floats*, the result is a little bit off:

```
math_ops.pow(2., 13)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=8191.996>
```

System details:

- OS: Linux Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)
- Tensorflow version: 2.11.1
- Python version: 3.8.10
- CUDA version: 12.0

Comment: Doesn't a simple tensor type cast work ? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast

Comment: You can cast the output, however that would give you the wrong result since it rounds the number down to the closest integer. Casting the inputs to int before computing the power of two does give you the right answer, but I don't get why this should be necessary.

Comment: I suppose it has something to do with the way TensorFlow handles `float32` math on GPUs, with some kind of optimization and imprecision. You get the correct result with `float64` and an imprecise, but same, result with `float16` on CPU and GPU. Interestingly, torch seems to handle it differently. There you get the correct result even with `float16`. (`torch.pow(t.cuda.HalfTensor([2]), t.cuda.HalfTensor([13]))`)